# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Found strange character

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I received the following when sending POST request

> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Found strange data: ?Color]
> My request body

```
{
    "name": "\bColor",
    "displayName": "\bColor",
    "position": 6
}
```

Controller

```
    @PostMapping("/name")
    public BaseResponseV2 saveNameField(@RequestBody NameField nameField) {
        nameService.saveFilterOption(nameField);
        return BaseResponseV2.makeResponse("DONE");
    }
```

NameField:

```
    private String name;
    private String displayName;
    private int position;
```

So How do I pass the special/strange character to RequestBody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the configuration of the `ObjectMapper` and add

```
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, true);
```

You can add something like

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
    return builder -> builder.json().featuresToEnable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER)
}
```

to a `@Configuration` annotated class to reconfigure the mapper

Comment: Hi @Jens!
The problem is the error occurred when the request hit the controller I mentioned.
And I tried using 
spring.jackson.parser.allow-backslash-escaping-any-character=true
in application.properties but the problem still persist